# Trouble with Google Earth Engine - cannot identify why chart is not generating - no features contain non-null values

Tags: google-earth-engine, google

Having some issues in GEE - it continuously states:
*Error generating chart: No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start".*
However, there are plenty of images that it could draw from - so why would it be null?

[image]

```
// Define user inputs
var farmName = prompt("Enter your farm name:");
var diversifyYear = parseInt(prompt("Enter the year of diversification:"));
var treeSpeciesCount = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of tree species on the farm:"));
// Create a map to display your results
var map = ui.Map();
map.setCenter(-93.81452, 41.47847, 15);
map.setOptions({ style: 'SATELLITE' });

// User inputs for each tree species
var treeSpeciesData = [];
var totalNumTrees = 0; // Initialize total number of trees

for (var i = 0; i < treeSpeciesCount; i++) {
  var speciesName = prompt("Enter tree species name:");
  var plantingDate = prompt("Enter planting date for " + speciesName + ":");
  var numTrees = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of trees planted for " + speciesName + ":"));
  treeSpeciesData.push({
    name: speciesName,
    datePlanted: plantingDate,
    numTrees: numTrees
  });
  totalNumTrees += numTrees; // Update total number of trees
}

// Calculate farm area
// Assuming you have farmBoundary defined elsewhere
var mergedFarmBoundary = farmBoundary.geometry().dissolve(1); // Use an error margin of 1 (you can adjust this value as needed)

// Calculate the area of the merged farm boundary in hectares with 2 decimal places
var farmArea = ee.Number(mergedFarmBoundary.area().divide(10000)).format('%.2f'); // in hectares (as a string with 2 decimal places)

// Calculate Shannon Index
var shannonIndexValue = 0; // Initialize Shannon Index value

for (var i = 0; i < treeSpeciesCount; i++) {
  var relativeAbundance = treeSpeciesData[i].numTrees / totalNumTrees; // Calculate p_i
  if (relativeAbundance > 0) {
    shannonIndexValue -= relativeAbundance * Math.log(relativeAbundance); // Calculate p_i * ln(p_i)
  }
}
shannonIndexValue = shannonIndexValue.toFixed(4); // Round Shannon Index to 4 decimal places

// Calculate Simpson Index
var simpsonIndexValue = 0; // Initialize Simpson Index value

for (var i = 0; i < treeSpeciesCount; i++) {
  var relativeAbundance = treeSpeciesData[i].numTrees / totalNumTrees; // Calculate p_i
  simpsonIndexValue += relativeAbundance * (relativeAbundance - 1); // Calculate Σ(ni * (ni - 1))
}
simpsonIndexValue = (1 / simpsonIndexValue).toFixed(4); // Calculate Simpson Index as 1 / Σ(ni * (ni - 1)) and round to 4 decimal places

// Descriptions of Simpson Index values
var simpsonDescription = "";
if (simpsonIndexValue < 0.7) {
  simpsonDescription = "Low Diversity (Dominance): When the Simpson Index is close to 0, it indicates low diversity, which means that one or a few species dominate the community. In ecological terms, this might suggest a lack of species richness or a situation where a single species predominates.";
} else if (simpsonIndexValue <= 0.7 && simpsonIndexValue < 1) {
  simpsonDescription = "Medium Diversity: A Simpson Index value between 0 and 0.7 may be considered a moderate level of diversity. It suggests that there is some level of evenness among the species present, but one or a few species may still dominate to some extent.";
} else {
  simpsonDescription = "High Diversity (Evenness): When the Simpson Index is close to 1, it suggests high diversity and evenness among species. In such cases, there is a relatively equal distribution of individuals among different species, and no single species dominates the community.";
}

// Calculate Species Richness
var speciesRichnessValue = treeSpeciesCount;

// Convert the diversifyYear to a timestamp in milliseconds
var diversifyYearMillis = ee.Date.fromYMD(diversifyYear, 1, 1).millis();

// Filter Sentinel-2 imagery by date and location
var sentinelCollection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filterBounds(mergedFarmBoundary)
  .filterDate(diversifyYearMillis, Date.now()) // Use the converted timestamp
  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 20); // Optionally, filter by cloud cover percentage

// Print the number of images in the collection to check
print("Number of Images in Collection:", sentinelCollection.size());

// Check the first image's properties to verify 'system:time_start' is available
var firstImage = sentinelCollection.first();
print("First Image Properties:", firstImage);

// Calculate NDVI for each image in the collection
var ndviCollection = sentinelCollection.map(function (image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']); // Calculate NDVI using Sentinel-2 bands B8 (NIR) and B4 (Red)
  return ndvi.set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
});

// Calculate the mean NDVI for the farm area
var meanNdvi = ndviCollection.mean()
  .clip(mergedFarmBoundary); // Clip to the farm boundary

// Visualize the NDVI
map.addLayer(meanNdvi, {
  min: -1,
  max: 1,
  palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']
}, 'Mean NDVI');

// Display the Shannon Index as a text label on the map
var shannonIndexLabel = ui.Label('Shannon Index: ' + shannonIndexValue);
shannonIndexLabel.style().set({
  position: 'top-right',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontSize: '16px',
  padding: '10px'
});
map.add(shannonIndexLabel);

// Descriptions of Shannon Index values
var shannonDescription = "";
if (shannonIndexValue < 1) {
  shannonDescription = "Low Diversity: A low Shannon Index value (close to 0) indicates low diversity, which suggests that one or a few species dominate the community, and there is limited species richness. This is similar to the interpretation for the Simpson Index.";
} else if (shannonIndexValue >= 1 && shannonIndexValue <= 2) {
  shannonDescription = "Medium Diversity: A Shannon Index value between 1 and 2 may be considered a moderate level of diversity. It suggests that there is some diversity in the community, but one or a few species may still be more abundant or dominant.";
} else {
  shannonDescription = "High Diversity: A high Shannon Index value (greater than 2) suggests high diversity with evenness among species. In this case, there is a wide variety of species present, and they are relatively evenly distributed in terms of abundance.";
}

// Calculate NDVI change over time
var seasonalNDVI = ndviCollection.map(function(image) {
  var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'));
  var year = date.get('year');
  
  // Define the dates for equinoxes and solstices
  var springEquinox = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 3, 20);
  var summerSolstice = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 6, 21);
  var fallEquinox = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 9, 23);
  var winterSolstice = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 12, 21);

  // Determine the season based on the image date
  var season;
  if (ee.Filter.gte(date, springEquinox) && ee.Filter.lt(date, summerSolstice)) {
    season = 'Spring';
  } else if (ee.Filter.gte(date, summerSolstice) && ee.Filter.lt(date, fallEquinox)) {
    season = 'Summer';
  } else if (ee.Filter.gte(date, fallEquinox) && ee.Filter.lt(date, winterSolstice)) {
    season = 'Fall';
  } else {
    season = 'Winter';
  }
  
  return image.set('season', season);
});

// Filter out images without 'system:time_start'
seasonalNDVI = seasonalNDVI.filterMetadata('system:time_start', 'not_equals', null);

// Calculate seasonal means
var seasonalMeans = seasonalNDVI.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).rename(['mean']);

// Create a chart for NDVI over seasons
var seasonChart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: seasonalMeans,
  regions: mergedFarmBoundary,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 10, // Adjust the scale for Sentinel-2
  xProperty: 'system:time_start',
  seriesProperty: 'season'
}).setChartType('LineChart').setOptions({
  title: 'Seasonal NDVI Change',
  hAxis: {
    title: 'Year'
  },
  vAxis: {
    title: 'NDVI'
  },
  lineWidth: 2,
  pointSize: 4
});

// Add the seasonal NDVI chart to the map
seasonChart.style({
  position: 'bottom-right',
  width: '500px',
  height: '300px',
  padding: '10px'
});
map.add(seasonChart);

// Print the seasonal NDVI chart to the console
print(seasonChart);

// Display outputs
print("Farm Name: " + farmName);
print("Diversification Year: " + diversifyYear);
print("Total Farm Area (Hectares): " + farmArea.getInfo()); // Display the farm area as a single number
print("Shannon Index: " + shannonIndexValue);
print("Simpson Index: " + simpsonIndexValue);
print("Species Richness: " + speciesRichnessValue);
print("Simpson Index Description: " + simpsonDescription);
print("Shannon Index Description: " + shannonDescription);
```

Comment: Can you make a smaller reproducible example? However, I can already see a problem: you are reducing (ee.Reducer.mean()) an image collection and then using the result (an ee.Image) as the input for a seriesByRegion chart. I don't think this is what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Many, many problems with this script, but:

1. You're charting using seasonlMeans, which is a single image.  There's no time-series data in there.  You probably meant to use seasonalNDVI.
2. The function you're using on seasonalNDVI can't work.
   You're using client-side if statements in your function, which aren't allowed. (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server#conditionals)
   Additionlly, you're using them on computedObjects, which can never work (client-server doesn't work like that).  And you're using ee.Filter objects, which don't do anything; they're used in filter functions, so doing any kind of conditional test with them is impossible, irrespective of whether you're doing client-side or server-side testing.

Rather than trying to do imperative comparisons like this (ie: iterating over each element to test what season it belongs to), you would get a better result if you filter the collection into 4 pieces based on dates of seasons (see calendarRange), assign the proper season to the 4 resulting collections and merge them back together.